# If all Total order relations are partial order as well, what about < relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

We know that < is total order as it satisfies all three properties antisymmetry, transitivity and connex but since it can not be reflexive we can say it will not be partial order.

But I have been reading that a total order is also a partial order

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing: $<$ is *not* a total order relation.  It is a **strict total order** relation.  These are irreflexive.  Total orders are reflexive.

$<$ does **not** have the *connex* property.  It is not true that $(a<b)\lor (b<a)$ for all $a$, $b$.

Rather, $<$ is trichotomous with equality: $(a< b)\oplus(b<a)\oplus(a=b)$.

Comment: So can we say that a strict total order relation is not a total order relation?

Comment: Yes, indeed we can.

Answer (score 0):

Authors are a bit sloppy about what they mean by "total order", because it doesn't actually matter very much as long as context is clear.

Any *weak* total order (i.e. "reflexive antisymmetric transitive trichotomous relation") implies a *strict* total order by defining $x < y$ to be "$x \leq y$ and $x \not = y$".

Conversely, any *strict* total order implies a *weak* total order by defining $x \lesssim y$ to be "$x < y$ or $x = y$".

Comment: so can I say that < is total order?

Comment: If you are happy being sloppy, and it's clear from context what you mean, then yes. In the context of an exam, no.